# I can't add comments to my own question that was asked as guest

Tags: support, comments, unregistered-users

I've asked this question as a guest
[Burn smell from arduino uno](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/41700/burn-smell-from-arduino-uno)

Now, I think I had account on stackoverflow with the SAME EMAIL ADDRESS
When I tried to login with that email I just get this new account I'm writing from now and can't add comments to my question.
So, What can I do ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: I can login with this account but the other one is UNREGISTERED.

Comment: Normally you'd just contact us, select other if the automated system doesn't work for you. I've gone ahead and merged your accounts, though.

Comment: @animuson hey, can you please spare a moment for [this similar case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335791/why-i-cant-comment-back-when-my-question-have-comment-by-other)? Thanks. :)