# Why can't I comment back when my question has been commented by others?

Tags: support, comment-replies

After asking a question in [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) using a guest account, I have signed up using the verification link in my mailbox. But now logging into the same mail, I cannot comment back on a comment asked by other members regarding the question asked previously. I want to let others understand the situation.

Comment: As the author of the post, you can comment under your post. If you want to comment elsewhere you need 50 rep. It's the rules.

Comment: As I asked the question from guest account, probably the system could not able to connect my login as both guest account and newly created account have the same email.

Comment: I think probably this is a bug

Comment: It might have accidentally created two accounts, I've seen it a few times, follow the instructions to [merge them here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: Thanks @TheLethalCoder , probably you are right. I have requested to merge.

Comment: The "Special Note" in the FAQ [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) addresses this question.

Comment: I checked and saw you can now reply in your post, congratulations!  But you should preface your comment with @ and the username, e.g. @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog to be sure that the user receives a notification. And I would fix the spelling of skewed in the title too, careless misspelling tends to make a poor impression.